# Use setImageTintMode in Android API < 21

Tags: android, imageview, material-design, android-support-library

I was looking at an `ImagView` tutorial. It mentions `setImageTintMode` method that was introduced in **API 21** of Android. *My question is can it be used in APIs lower than 21 (Lollipop) ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `setImageTintMode` requires API 21+.

You can use something like this:

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `setImageTintMode` cannot be used in APIs lower than 21.

However, you can use `setColorFilter` instead, as this can be used in all API levels and will produce a similar result:

```
imageView.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, Mode.MULTIPLY )
```

The second parameter is the tint mode and the first is the color of the tint to be applied.